# writing output file as .txt or .csv to script containing multiple conditions

Tags: powershell

I have written a script which checks a service status, tests two paths and also tests a registry value.  Currently I am getting output on the power shell console (that could be because I am using write-output command). 
Is there any way to write the single one page output to a file?
I am struggling to find a way to out-file entire output to a file.

Below is the script.

```
$testpath = Test-Path "C:\test" 
$testpath2 = test-path "C:\test"  
$mcshieldk = Get-Service -Name mcshield | select Name  
$internet = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\internet explorer").MkEnabled $hostname = hostname  Write-Host "hostname of comuter is" $hostname if (Test-Path $Machinetype)
{}  
else { Write-Host "internet is" $internet }  
if ($testpath -eq $true -and $testpath2 -eq $true) 
 {  Write-Host "test and test1 folder exists" -ForegroundColor Green  }  
else{ Write-Host "folder does not exists" -ForegroundColor Red  }  if($mcshield.Name -eq "mcshield") { Write-Host "mcshield service exists" }  
else { Write-Host "mcshield does not exists"  }
```

Below is the console output

```
hostname of comuter is Server1
internet is Yes
test and test1 folder exists
mcshield  does not exists
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap out your `Write-Host` cmdlets or add in another line with the following:

```
"Your output text $YourVariable" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Log.txt" -Append -Encoding utf8
```

This will append a string to the end of the log file `C:\Log.txt`. **Note**, missing the `-Append` parameter will cause the file to be overwritten.

You can also use the follow to give the same affect:

```
"Your output text $YourVariable" >> "C:\Log.txt"
```

But be carefully not to mix the two methods as you might get encoding errors in the text file. If you wish to overwrite the file with the second method use `>` instead of `>>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard. that was quick support. it worked. :-)

Comment: Did it Richard.. I have just started sites so was not aware of this.. appreciate your quick support, :-) cheers!